# Cant start flask app using gunicorn on ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, https, gunicorn

Hello guys so I am trying to make flask app running on ubuntu server and i get this error every time i try to start it. I got here so far

```
× flaskapp.service - Flask App
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/flaskapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-06-27 11:35:53 UTC; 14min ago
    Process: 1689 ExecStart=/home/maxnet/.local/bin/gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:443 --certfile=/var/www/flaskapp/certs/cert.pem --keyfile=/var/www/flaskapp/certs/key.pem app:app (code=exited,>
   Main PID: 1689 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 553ms

Jun 27 11:35:47 ubuntu-dev01 systemd[1]: Started Flask App.
Jun 27 11:35:48 ubuntu-dev01 gunicorn[1689]: [2023-06-27 11:35:48 +0000] [1689] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Jun 27 11:35:48 ubuntu-dev01 gunicorn[1689]: [2023-06-27 11:35:48 +0000] [1689] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Jun 27 11:35:49 ubuntu-dev01 gunicorn[1689]: [2023-06-27 11:35:49 +0000] [1689] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Jun 27 11:35:50 ubuntu-dev01 gunicorn[1689]: [2023-06-27 11:35:50 +0000] [1689] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Jun 27 11:35:51 ubuntu-dev01 gunicorn[1689]: [2023-06-27 11:35:51 +0000] [1689] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Jun 27 11:35:52 ubuntu-dev01 gunicorn[1689]: [2023-06-27 11:35:52 +0000] [1689] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Jun 27 11:35:53 ubuntu-dev01 gunicorn[1689]: [2023-06-27 11:35:53 +0000] [1689] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 443)
Jun 27 11:35:53 ubuntu-dev01 systemd[1]: flaskapp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 27 11:35:53 ubuntu-dev01 systemd[1]: flaskapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
~
```

I think this is some permision stuff but not sure. I have to be honest that i dont use ubuntu server that often. Also want to mention that i NEED it to run on port 443. I was reading something about ports that are less than 1024 are privileged but actually dont know what to do with that.

(This is my first post, if is something missing just tell me i will try to provide more)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so basicly what i did was snooping around and finding out and in flask app i had set `port=443` and i just deleted and it works.

...After month